# How can create a function using variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, variables, dataset

I'm sure the question is a bit dummy (sorry)... I'm trying to create a function using differents variables I have stored in a Dataframe. The function is like that:

```
mlr_turb <- function(Cond_in, Flow_in, pH_in, pH_out, Turb_in, nm250_i, nm400_i, nm250_o, nm400_o){

     Coag = (+0.032690 + 0.090289*Cond_in + 0.003229*Flow_in - 0.021980*pH_in - 0.037486*pH_out 
             +0.016031*Turb_in  -0.026006*nm250_i +0.093138*nm400_o - 0.397858*nm250_o - 0.109392*nm400_o)/0.167304

    return(Coag)
    }

m4_turb <- mlr_turb(dataset)
```

The problem is when I try to run my function in a dataframe (with the same name of variables). It doesn't detect my variables and shows this message:

```
Error in mlr_turb(dataset) : 
  argument "Flow_in" is missing, with no default
```

But, actually, there is, also all the variables.

**I think I missplace or missing some order in the function that gives it the possibility to take the variables from the dataset. I have searched a lot about that but I have not found any answer...**

Comment: You're currently telling it that `Cond_in = dataset` in your function... you need something more like `mlr_turb(dataset$Cond_in, dataset$Flow_in ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meet a standard problem when writing `R` that is related to the question of `standard evaluation` (SE) vs `non standard evaluation` (NSE). If you need more elements, you can have a look at [this blog post I wrote](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/)

I think the most convenient way to write function using variables is to use variable names as arguments of the function.

Let's take again @Muon example.

```r
# a simple function that takes x, y and z as arguments 
myFun <- function(x, y, z){
  result <- (x + y)/z
  return(result)
}
```

The question is where `R` should find the values behind names `x`, `y` and `z`. In a function, `R` will first look within the function environment (here `x`,`y` and `z` are defined as parameters) then it will look at global environment and then it will look at the different packages attached.

In `myFun`, `R` expects vectors. If you give a column name, you will experience an error. What happens if you want to give a column name ? You must say to `R` that the name you gave should be associated to a value in the scope of a dataframe. You can for instance do something like that:

```r
myFun <- function(df, col1 = "x", col2 = "y", col3 = "z"){
  result <- (df[,col1] + df[,col2])/df[,col3]
  return(result)
}
```

You can go far further in that aspect with `data.table` package. If you start writing functions that need to use variables from a dataframe, I recommend you to start having a look at this package

Answer (score 3):

No dumb questions!

I think you're looking for [do.call](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call). This function allows you to unpack values into a function as arguments. Here's a really simple example.

```
# a simple function that takes x, y and z as arguments 
myFun <- function(x, y, z){
  result <- (x + y)/z
  return(result)
}

# a simple data frame with columns x, y and z
myData <- data.frame(x=1:5,
                     y=(1:5)*pi,
                     z=(11:15))

# unpack the values into the function using do.call
do.call('myFun', myData)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] 0.3765084 0.6902654 0.9557522 1.1833122 1.3805309
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Muon's answer, but I couldn't get it to work if there are columns in the data.frame not in the function.  Using the with() function is a simple way to make this work as well...

```
#Code from Muon:
# a simple function that takes x, y and z as arguments 
myFun <- function(x, y, z){
  result <- (x + y)/z
  return(result)
}

# a simple data frame with columns x, y and z
myData <- data.frame(x=1:5,
                     y=(1:5)*pi,
                     z=(11:15), 
                     a=6:10)    #adding a var not used in myFun
    
# unpack the values into the function using do.call
do.call('myFun', myData)
#generates an error for the unused "a" column

#using with() function:
with(myData, myFun(x, y, z))
```